# How can I prohibit movement of an element with jQueryUI sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Tell me please. How to prevent `.item` element from moving to `#block_1` but allow moving from `#block_1`.

```js
$("#block_1, #block_2").sortable({
  connectWith: ".block",
  placeholder: "placeholder",
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 49%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.block .item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.placeholder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-6XMVI0zB8cRzfZjqKcD01PBsAy3FlDASrlC8SxCpInY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="block" id="block_1">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="block" id="block_2">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please follow up with your question. You have an answer to which you have not responded. I see several other seemingly abandoned questions on your profile as well.

Answer (score 1):

You omit the `connectWith` option when initializing the `#block_2` sortable, like so:

```js
$("#block_1").sortable({
  connectWith: ".block",
  placeholder: "placeholder"
});

$("#block_2").sortable({
  // note: no connectWith option -> items cannot leave this sortable
  placeholder: "placeholder",
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 49%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.block .item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.placeholder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-6XMVI0zB8cRzfZjqKcD01PBsAy3FlDASrlC8SxCpInY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="block" id="block_1">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="block" id="block_2">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```